# A simple way to display images on Ubuntu using c++ code

Tags: image, ubuntu, video, error-handling, gtk

I have installed `xorg, openbox, fbdev and libgtk-3-dev` on Ubuntu-server 16.04, and tried this code(I found it inside other question)to show an image:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void destroy(void) {
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  GtkWidget* window;
  GtkWidget* image;

  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);


  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  image  = gtk_image_new_from_file(argv[1]);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",
             G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), image);

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

And could compile successfully by this command:

```
    gcc -Wall imageTest.c -o img `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

But when I try `img 1.png` for example, the result is:

```
(process:1338): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Failed to connect to Mir: Failed to connect to server socket: No such file or directory
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(img:1338): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attached a USB keyboard to my board and tried to run my program inside it's terminal directly and it worked without problem and showed my picture inside my SPI LCD.

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is a GTK 2 example, not GTK 3. Stuff like `GTK_OBJECT` or `gtk_signal_connect` were moved long time ago from GTK to GLib.

You have GTK 3 [application examples in the GTK 3 documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html#id-1.2.3.12.5), or on the [platform-demos](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/hello-world.html.fr).

As for `argv[1]`, please look for C tutorials about `argc` and `argv`, they're the way you pass command line arguments to a program (and no, that's not linux-specific).

Comment: Hi and thanks, but before saw your answer, I did change my code and get new error. I edited my post and please read it.

Comment: Then you should have asked another question as the problem is different. Are you able to start a working graphical environment? It seems your Xorg server is not started.

Comment: yes, I can run this command `FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb8 startx` and I have a gray screen with mouse and right-click menu.  But I am looking for a way to permanent this settings too here: https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/1213093/How-to-set-SPI-LCD-to-be-default-display-on-ubuntu?pgnumcmt2_1213093=2#answer1

Comment: Should I install some extra package like xdm?